# What's wrong with this web.xml file? The content of web-app must match

Tags: eclipse, web.xml

The following `web.xml` file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>exclusions</param-name>
            <param-value>css,images,js</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>root_controller</param-name>
            <param-value>home</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

causes Eclipse to swear that

```
The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)".
```

i.e. no obligatory tags.

What is it dislike?

**UPDATE**

Error disappears if I remove `filter` and `filter-mapping` tags simultaneously. Unfortunately I need them and can't remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your elements must match the order they're listed in the error message. Try putting your `filter` and `filter-mapping` elements before your `session-config` element.